# mySQL sphinx Index location on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, sphinx

I am trying to test out a Sphinx cookbook, but I need a database to do so.

I have created the database locally, but I need to know where the default path is for the index of the table I created.

This is the error I am currently getting when trying to run sphinx because the path to the index is wrong:

```
WARNING: index 'phoneindex': preload: failed to open /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sph: No such       file or directory; NOT SERVING
FATAL: no valid indexes to serve
```

Where can I find mysql.sph? Or how/when is that file created?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your question about MySQL MyISAM index files located in ``/var/lib/mysql/databasename/tablename.MYI`` or Sphinx index files?

Comment: Actually, I guess it is the Sphinx index files...
Do i create them?

Comment: ok, I got it to work. I had to index it first using `sudo indexer -c /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf phoneindex`.
Thanks for pointing out what I should actually be looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing some things:

An indexer READS your MySQL data through a connection on the MySQL service, not by reading the MySQL files.

Your index would be in the Sphinx data repository set in the Sphinx conf for each index with a path parameter.

```
index myindex{
source = ...
path = /path/to/your/sphinx/data
}
```